# Spring Boot - Where to put properties files when deploying to Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I've been using `Spring Boot` for a few weeks already, and I'm used to work with the `application.properties` file. I'm able to use it for simple deployment and use with `java jar` or `mvn spring-boot:run`.

Now I'm trying to deploy my application to a `Tomcat 8.0.15` application server. I've been reading of documentation, but I can't deploy the `war` file because Tomcat can't find this famous `application.properties` file. My point is, if I want to put this file out of the `war`, where in my Tomcat installation should I put it for it to be automatically read?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to change it later, just put it in the root of your classpath, e.g. if it's Maven project then inside

```
<project-folder>/src/main/java/
```

If you want to change it later without rebuilding WAR then in Tomcat properties file

```
catalina.properties
```

there is

```
shared.loader=
```

that makes properties files listed after equals sign accessible to deployed applications. Better use absolute paths.

BTW, I would opt to use annotation-based configuration nowadays, but then again, it doesn't have the comfort of changing without rebuilding WAR.

Comment: I would like to know, how Spring boot loads catalina.properties file?

Answer (score 3):

Spring loads the properties from

```
   1) A /config subdir of the current directory.
   2) The current directory
   3) A classpath /config package
   4) The classpath root
```

See the docs(23.2 Application property files):
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

This should work the same way for war(The classpath root one looks the best for me) .

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me to put my properties file at the right place for it to be loaded by my app. But it didn't answer my original question. My main question was how to externalise it.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide the location of properties file as part of "JAVA_OPTS" in catalina.sh/catalina.batch or setEnv.bat/setEnv.sh.
set JAVA_OPTS=-Dspring.config.location=file:/D:/Appconfig/application.properties

Just for info:application.yaml will not be loaded by spring boot if outside war and defined like above.